# what does "int x = type(int).min;" mean in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, data-types

In the Solidity docs,
"if you have int x = type(int).min;, then -x does not fit the positive range.This means that unchecked { assert(-x == x); } works, and the expression -x when used in checked mode will result in a failing assertion."

.min gives the lowest value, so if its a signed int then "int x = type(int).min" will be a very high negative number? In that case shouldn't -x be positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type(int256).min` is  `-57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968`, while `type(int256).max` is `57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819967`.

If `x` was equal to `type(int256).min`, then the theoretic `-x` will certainly be greater than `type(int256).max` by 1 and it will not fit the positive number scale, therefore when computed in code it will overflow and the resulting value will be on the exact opposite side on the far end of the negative number scale due to the way numbers are represented digitally and how binary number addition works. That means that the result of `-x` would be equal to `x`, given that we're allowing for number overflows, and thus the unchecked math block `unchecked { assert(-x == x); }` would work. But when used in checked mode, it will result in a failing transaction since that's the default Solidity behavior for handling number overflows after version 0.8.0.